# Android -Manage recyclerview header and footer

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Maybe this question has been asked before, but I could not seem to find a precise answer or solution. I have got a suggestion use for a **sticky header** but I don't have to use it as the requirement is not that.

I have tried some code to manage the position. But didn't get proper output.

**Here is my code:**

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return attachmentModelList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (showHeaderAboveItem(position) && attachmentModelList.size() >= 0) {
        if (!Utils.compareTwoDates(Utils.parseDate(attachmentModelList.get(position).getCreatedOn(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"), Utils.parseDate(attachmentModelList.get(position + 1).getCreatedOn(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")) {
            return SECTION_VIEW;
        } else {
            return CONTENT_VIEW;
        }
    }

}
private boolean showHeaderAboveItem(int itemAdapterPosition) {
    if (itemAdapterPosition == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return itemAdapterPosition - 1 != itemAdapterPosition;
}
```

**I want to manage position same like the image.**

[image]

Comment: What is your question...?

Comment: I want to manage position of header look above image

Comment: what you get so far? put your current output and expected output